# How can I stop VI from overlapping and hiding the last page of command line output?

Tags: bash, vim, vi, gnu-screen

Currently, when I start vi in a terminal window within screen, the vi program takes up the full screen and covers up any of the output history that was there, and then remains there upon exiting. Thus, when scrolling back through my terminal output at a later time, the output under the vi window is masked.

I'm currently working around this with the following alias in my bashrc...

`alias vi='for i in $( seq 1 $LINES ); do echo ; done ; vi'`

This has worked just fine so far, but it strikes me as kind of kludgy and I fear I'm going to hit an unforeseen situation where it fails me at some point. I was wondering if there's a command option for either vi or screen or some other simpler, more efficient way of achieving the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use GNU Screen, the following line in your .screenrc should solve the problem:

```
altscreen on
```

This will ensure that the old contents is restored after you exit Vi, and it won't clutter your scrollback history anymore.

Comment: Thanks, this works for clearing the vi window when exiting (similarly to how it works when not using GNU Screen).

Comment: thanks this works. only problem is it still covers output history when vi is open( if you use the mousewheel to pan up). One way around this is to use ctrl+z to send vi to the background so you can view the terminal output, and then fg when you want to go back. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `set t_ti= t_te=` to your .vimrc file.

To fix less which also exhibits this behavior, set `export LESS=-X` in your .bashrc file.

Note: Some terminals such as urxvt are able to fix this globally for all ncurses program with a settings like this: `urxvt*secondaryScreen: false`

Comment: Why should the LESS enviroment variable affect Vi?

Comment: @Adam: I was answering the wrong question. I saw and upvoted your fix for GNU screen. Such a fix also exists outside of screen for some terminals such as the one I use, see my edited answer. The programs can usually be fixed one by one as well in their own configs.

Comment: You are a hero. Have been looking for `t_ti` and `t_te` for over an hour. Fixed my problem (although not entirely related to this question). Thanks!