# How to display previous shell commands after exiting vim in macOS Terminal?

Tags: bash, vim, screen

I'm using the macOS Terminal app.  When I exit vim, the text of the file I was editing remains on my screen and overlaps the commands I typed previously, so I can't see any of my previous commands.  How can I change this behavior so I can see my previous commands?

I've found this post
[How can I stop VI from overlapping and hiding the last page of command line output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049716/how-can-i-stop-vi-from-overlapping-and-hiding-the-last-page-of-command-line-outp)
but I don't see the `altscreen` command.

Comment: `altscreen` is a GNU screen command which should be available for OSX. Try typing `screen` at the terminal.

Comment: thanks Thor, I'm now doing 'man screen' to see what it can do.

Answer (score 3):

`altscreen` is only useful if you use Vim inside a `screen` session. If you don't, it's irrelevant.

In iTerm, the behavior you describe is controlled by the *Disable save/restore alternate screen* checkbox in the *Preferences* window:

`Profiles > Terminal > Disable save/restore alternate screen > (uncheck the checkbox)`

Uncheck it to get your previous prompts and command outputs back.

In Terminal, the default behavior is the one you want and I don't see anything in the options that would change it.